# cannot execute the delete query

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables : `details` and `Product`

Both the tables have a field `user_id`. It is the primary key in the table order and 
in the table Product i have created a foreign key.I execute the following query.
Initially the tables had two records one with `user_id=11` and and other with `user_id=12`
I executed the following script

```
// making the database connection
$db2=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("my_requests",$db2);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT details.*,product.* FROM details INNER JOIN product ON details.user_id = product.user_id"); 


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id=$row['user_id'];
echo "$id";

$query1=mysql_query("DELETE FROM details WHERE details.user_id=$id");    
$query2=mysql_query("DELETE FROM product WHERE product.user_id=$id");
}
```

On execution it just deleted the record with user_id=12.
When i tried to execute it again neither did it echo anything nor did it delete the remaining record.

please rectify.sorry for the bad english.

i printed this at the end of the loop:

> printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

It did not display anything

Comment: Use this to check on number of affected rows: echo("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows()); Also, should this be $id=$row['product.user_id']; ??

Comment: It is recommended to use PDO for mysql queries now. It is much more secure. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Nothing wrong in the code. Are you sure about the content of the tables?

Comment: check record in the database ... if it is deleted then it will not get deleted another time.

Comment: Sure of database content and structure?

Comment: yeah i am pretty sure of the schema :

user_id is the primary key of the details table,
using the user_id in product table i refernced it(Created a foregin key) to the details table.

Comment: @MichaelManoochehri $id=$row['product.user_id'] , ithink it is not necessary beacuse i have already takken the innerjoin above

Answer (score 1):

try to use  `mysql_affected_rows()` this way you can be sure if Rows are getting delete , DELETE query would succeed even if no rows are affected

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_affected_rows() to check affected id
```

and i think your database do not have anything to display on second run

Comment: checked again database still has the record with user_id =11

Comment: try this before while loop var_dump($query), you will be able to see records fetched from previous query